# Assistance with CNAME records maybe?

Tags: domain-name-system

Let me preface this by saying I think this is a systems duty and I'm in networking so I may not even be accurate in my question.

I received a request to provide a list of domains which are pointing to abc.company.com. I believe this request means they are looking for all the CNAME records which point to abc.company.com. For example, I type internetpage.com in my browser and I'm redirected to abc.company.com. Is there a way I can easily find every record that will point me to abc.company.com? Maybe our authoritative DNS will have that data? I have no idea. How would I go about doing this?

Will exchange my BGP/OSPF knowledge for your DNS knowledge. :)

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP redirects? If so, then that has nothing to do with DNS. _Any_ webserver in the world can issue an HTTP redirect to `http://abc.company.com/`.

Answer (score 2):

If all the names that are pointing at `abc.company.com` are within zones (domains) that your company controls, then you need to be looking in the zone files on your DNS server(s).

If people have aliases pointing to `abc.company.com` from outside of your company, like what might happen if you were doing some kind of web hosting.  There simply is no good way to find all of the names with any level of certainty.  If all the requests handled by `abc.company.com` are http/https you might be able to log and capture the http host headers used in the http request, which should give you probably the best approximation of what names are pointing at that system.

If you have outside names pointing to `abc.company.com` and you cant examine logs or capture headers `abc.company.com` traffic you are mostly out of luck.